# Return multiple instead of one in Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get data out of the mySQL database but for somereason only one returns. Here is the table in the database:
`select * from locations;`

```
+----+------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+------------+
| id | account_id | name             | created_at          | updated_at          | location_code | deleted_at |
+----+------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+------------+
|  1 |          1 | Default Location | 2018-01-05 19:56:11 | 2018-01-05 19:56:11 | 86A8-6070     | NULL       |
|  2 |          1 | Testing          | 2018-01-07 15:15:16 | 2018-01-07 15:15:16 | BA5D-C4FD     | NULL       |
+----+------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+------------+
```

And here is my call:

```
$locationSettings = Location::find($user->account_id);                    
\Log::info($locationSettings);
```

And... here is what it returns:

```
[2018-01-07 21:19:47] local.INFO: {"id":1,"account_id":1,"name":"Default Location","created_at":"2018-01-05 19:56:11","updated_at":"2018-01-05 19:56:11","location_code":"86A8-6070","deleted_at":null} [] []
```

How come it does not return both entries in the table since both of them have the matching account_id?

Comment: find only returns the first object that was found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try
`$locationSettings = Location::where('account_id', $user->account_id)->get();`

The `find()` method will only return one record by default.  You want a collection so will need the where clause using `get()`.

Comment: That is perfect! So `Find` only returns the first object. This makes a whole lot more sense! Best Answer when it is available.

Comment: `find()` actually looks at the `id` column by default, so when you're saying `find(1)` it's actually giving you back the first record because that is the line with id = 1.